# EF CTP5 - Can't find "Database First" Examples

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm brand new to CTP, just downloaded CTP5.  I have an existing database that I have been constantly regenerating my *.edmx file from for months during iterative cycles of development.  One of the biggest headaches has been that every time I regen the *.edmx file I have to manually go in and fix things.  A HUGE time waste.  For instance, I have a table that has a BillingAddressID and HomeAddressID fields, both of which are FK's to my Address table.  When the EF Wizard generates my model for me these come out as Address and Address1.  I have to manually go into the designer and rename these to BillingAddress and HomeAddress.

I'm hoping that with CTP5 I can someone plug into the pipeline of generation and automatically fix the model each time I regenerate.  But all the examples out there seem to be "code first", I can't find any examples of how plug into the "database first" model generation code.

Can this be done with CTP5?  If so, can anyone point me to a tutorial or sample?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

It's not going to generate models for you, the point of codefirst is to write your own POCOs. But it does support the db-first scenario.

*Update*
I just did a quick experiment, and found that in scenarios where I renamed columns that the EDMX design tool generated (as per your example of what the problem w/ it is), I could still run the Update Model from Database tool (right click on design surface, choose Update Model From Database) and it would not overwrite my changes.

You're not hand-editing the generated code files are you?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm just getting caught up with CTP.  Again, that article, like everything I've read, doesn't have anything to do with generating my object model from a database.  I use the Entity Data Model Wizard which AFAIK, is still a viable tool (right??). It's whole purpose is to generated biz classes from db's and all I'm looking for is a way to have more control of the Wizard's creation of my objects!! Is CTP useless for me? Is $MS forcing its EF users to go code-first and db-first is outta luck?

Comment: Let me say it again, CodeFirst does not generate models for you.  The *point* of CodeFirst is to write your own models as POCOs and then either have them gen your DB or else wire them to an existing DB.  You can still use the EF data model wizard, but if you do you're not using CodeFirst, you're using the same tool you used before, and you're stuck w/ the same problems you had before.  No one is forcing you to use CodeFirst, it's an alternate approach that may or may not work for your dev style / scenario.

Comment: By forcing, what I mean is that it seems like the CTP ONLY has benefits in it for the code-first crowd.  From the beginning the EF toolkit has supported db-first so where are the new features and improvements there?  The current db-first tools have limitations and I'm drooling looking at the customization features I see for code-first, like the ability to customize code generation. I was hoping that this would be and upgrade to the ENTIRE product. So, I'll rephrase the question: does the next version of the EF tool suite have any improvements to the existing db-first workflow?????

Comment: @Paul - maybe I didn't describe my problem scenario clearly enough.  See my response to @Ladislav above, I'm generating my classes clean from my db, no updates.

Comment: @sisdog, no offense but you seem to be shooting yourself in the foot by regenerating the whole model each time. Of course you're going to lose your customizations then...  I've had no problems at all w/ the update feature, I'm not sure what you're seeing, sorry.

Comment: @Paul, it's been many months since I started this project so I've gone back to updating my model.  It's working better than before so I think applying the CTP fixed some things. So thx for the kick in the pants, I'll try working in this mode now. Last question: any tips on how to reconcile changes made in the DB to make sure they've gotten into the model?  Let's say I refactor a bunch of tables in the DB, I can "try" to remember to update all the model objects but I might miss one. Any cool ways to see a delta between db and model?

Comment: No way to visualize it that I know of, that'd be an interesting open source project for someone to take on.  I think in general that's one of the things that's done better in other frameworks, is the "migrations" story as either the DB or the code model updates.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what properties of your model are renamed? Changes made to entities (CSDL) are not modified when updating model from database. Only manual changes to SSDL (database description) are overwritten. Of course if you just delete your EDMX and let VS create the new one your changes are lost.

If you want to use [CTP5 features with EDMX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-model-amp-database-first-with-dbcontext.aspx) it is possible BUT you are using same EDMX as now so if you have some problems with EDMX processing this problems will persist.

Comment: Hey @Ladislav.  My problem isn't on updates to an existing model, it's on the initial creation of the model.  I've run into so many problems using the update feature of the model browser that I just completely regen my model when I have a db change. The URL you reference still describes a code-first approach.  I don't want to write my own classes that match to a db.  I'm looking to generate my biz classes from a db completely.  I keep all my custom biz logic in partial classes. This workflow has been working well for me, it's just time consuming in a few spots that I'm trying to remedy.

Comment: @sisdog: 1. use update from databse. It works if you use it the right way. I'm using it almost every day only with minor problems. 2. Read again the article. It doesn't use code-first. It uses EDMX and generates classes for you. If you don't get it just follow the article and try it yourselves.